# Strange Chinese Characters in Registry

Tags: registry

I was just taking a look at my registry editor when I noticed some strange folders in the bottom of the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT section. These folders are named 칞ꊟጀ耀 (No translation), 縀䆁 (No Translation, but is pronounced Xiá gāo) and 䈍麉ᄏ洳祕ā (translates to "The Secret") which is rather eerie to me.

Windows defender has not showed anything unusual and MalwareBytes didn't get rid of them either. Is there any way to see if these are malicious?

Comment: I googled "Strange Chinese Characters in Registry" and we were the top hit. Please make sure to look up issues you might have as the answers might be available.

Comment: @schroeder That other question's answers don't really tell me if the items I've found are malicious or not nor do they give me any way to check for myself. I'm just concerned with the one on my computer that actually translate into an understandable phrase. Something about "The Secret" simply screams that its hiding something so I figure my worrying is understandable.

Comment: Or, like the other answers show, it's a random translation. And yes, there are lots of steps provided for you to check. As you can see, the other questions also provided a lot more detail. All you've given us are Chinese characters. So, how can ***we*** determine if it is malicious or not? Rule out the things in the other answers, and check out *all the other hits from google* for that search term...

Comment: Also, do you really think a hacker is going to use the most used language in the world to edit your registry and use the label "The Secret" as a way of hiding something?